# Popping from a list in state while a condition is true

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, stack, monads

I'm dealing with data that stores its state as a `String`, treating the string like a stack. I also have to combine that with error handling.

To that end, I'm using the type `StateT String Maybe a`. I have a function to pop and to push a `Char` from and to the string:

```
pop :: StateT String Maybe Char
pop = do
    x:xs <- get
    put xs
    return x

push :: Char -> StateT String Maybe ()
push x = do
    xs <- get
    put (x:xs)
    return ()
```

I wrote a function to repeatedly `pop` from the string while the characters being popped fulfilled a condition. It behaves as follows:

```
> runStateT (popWhile (<'a')) "HELLO world"
Just ("HELLO ","world")

> runStateT (popWhile (>'a')) "HELLO world"
Just ("","HELLO world")
```

My implementation is the following:

```
popWhile :: (Char -> Bool) -> StateT String Maybe [Char]
popWhile f = do
    s <- get
    if null s
        then return []
        else popAgain

    where
        popAgain = do
            x <- pop
            if f x
                then liftM (x:) (popWhile f)
                else push x >> return []
```

But that seems pretty bulky, and has two `if then else`'s in it. Is there a better way to write this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using [span](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:span):

> `span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`
>
> `span`, applied to a predicate `p` and a list `xs`, returns a tuple where
>   first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of `xs` of elements
>   that satisfy `p` and second element is the remainder of the list

```
popWhile :: (Char -> Bool) -> StateT String Maybe String
popWhile p = do
    s <- get
    let (xs, ys) = span p s
    put ys
    return xs
```

---

Thanks to @bisserlis for the suggestion to use `state`

```
popWhile = state . span
```

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm still pretty beginner when it comes to monads in Haskell, so I've a lot to learn about writing functions like this. In that sense, this is a super helpful answer, so I'll be giving this the Green Tick of Doom.

Comment: @Matthew glad I could help :) [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a very useful resource for finding functions like `span`.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using that lately, particularly to deal with `Maybe`s. The trick with this though is that I need to use `get` and `put` directly and then jump into regular list functions; that wasn't obvious to me until now.

Comment: Use `state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a` to clean things up even further. I.E., `pop = state uncons` `push = state (:)` and `popWhile p = state (span p)`.

Comment: @bisserlis that's a great suggestion, thank you!